# Line of intersection of two planes in parametric form

Tags: analytic-geometry

You are given two planes in parametric form :

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{1} : \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} + u_1 \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{pmatrix} + v_1 \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
6\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{2} : \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
-1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix} + u_2 \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
3
\end{pmatrix} + v_2 \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

Substitute expressions for $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ from the parametric form of $S_{2}$ into Cartesian equation for $S_1$ and hence find a parametric vector form of the line of intersection $L$.

I found Cartesian equation for $S_1$ which is $2x_1-x_2+6x_3=0$. But when I substitute expressions from $S_2$, they come with $u_2$ and $v_2$ vectors. How can I eliminate them?

Comment: $u_1$ and $v_1$ aren’t vectors. They are scalar parameters. After substitution you’ve got a linear equation in these parameters, so solve for one in terms of the other.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write real numbers for $u_2$ and $v_2$. 
But I substitute the following expressions:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1 = u_2\\
x_2 = -1+2v_2\\
x_3 = -1 + 3u_2 +v_2
\end{eqnarray*}
into $S_1$.
\begin{equation*}
2(u_2)-(-1+2v_2)+6(-1+3u_2+v_2)=0\\
20u_2+4v_2=5
\end{equation*}
I don't know what I will do after solving one in terms of others..

Comment: Substitute back into $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you I solved it!

Comment: You should write your solution up as an answer to this question, then!

Answer (score 0):

Given plane $$S : \vec r = \vec a + u_1 \vec b + u_2 \vec c $$
Alternate way of interpreting this equation as the equation of plane spanned by the vectors $( \vec b - \vec a) = \vec r_1 $ and $(\vec c - \vec a) = \vec r_2$. The normal of the plane can be computed, as $\vec n = \vec r_1 \times \vec r_2 $ and other thing you need is a point which lies on the plane, which here is $\vec a$. Equation of the plane can be written as $ \vec r \cdot \vec n = \vec a \cdot \vec n$. If you will do so, you will obtain the equation of $S_2$ as $10x_1 + 2 x_2 - 3 x_3 = 1$

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, they want me to do a transition between parametric form of $S_2$ and Cartesian form of $S_1$. And finally find the intersection line in parametric form.

Comment: At last you have to find the parametric form of intersection of line, right? So what is the problem with my solution, you've got the equation of plane, now carry on.

Comment: @begbeg Do you have any problem with my approach?

Comment: Actually I solved before as you said for another part of the question. I mean I've already found the Cartesian equations for both planes and then find the parametric form of the line. But now they asked me specially solve in this way as a second method and compare with what I've found before. There is not any problem with your solution. But I don't think yours is what they asked.